# mPDF - Inline blocks not displaying side by side

Tags: javascript, php, css, mpdf

I have a bunch of small tables that are formatted as inline-block elements. In the browser they display side by side as intended, but when using mPDF to output them they break after each table. No matter how I try to format them, they always break after the table. Is there a trick with mPDF to get elements to stack side-by-side?

I am pulling the exact HTML from the page and sending it via AJAX

Below is an example of the browser and pdf view.

[image: HTML View]

[image: PDF View]

My mPDF generator page looks like this:

```
<?php
include("mpdf60/mpdf.php");

$html = $_POST['html'];

$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4');
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

// LOAD a stylesheet
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('../../_css/main.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);    // The parameter 1 tells that this is css/style only and no body/html/text

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('myPDF.pdf','D');

exit;
?>
```

Comment: Can we see the main.css? Looks like the width of both tables are too big to align them next to eachother. Keep in mind that the width of a mPDF page is around 800 pixels i believe.

Comment: That was my first thought so I tried putting the tables at 100px and it did not make a difference in their behavior.

Comment: Weird! But we can't see much without the CSS file. Also, which version of mPDF do you use?

Comment: I dont believe the CSS is going to help. I stripped out the CSS file from above code and ran it with just default html table styles (with the exception of inline styling the tables as inline-block elements) and it is displaying the same. I am on mPDF version 6.0.

Answer (score 11):

I try a lot of thinks too, but finally i found a solution, just use:

```
float: left;
```

Thats work for me.

Comment: Please note that just using `float: left;` is not enough as you need to explicitly set a width on the element, as mentioned by [the docs](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/floating-blocks.html).

Answer (score 8):

I've spent a couple of hours figuring out how to make inline `<div>` or `<p>` elements with mPDF. I found some [limitations](https://mpdf.github.io/about-mpdf/limitations.html), which contains the inline-block too. The `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` is ignored. You have to put everything in `<span>` elements if you want to see them one beside the other.

Comment: Thanks bro it works for me `<span style="display: inline-flex"><span>test 1</span><span>test 2</span>
</span>`

Comment: @Sobir, as mPDF [does not have support](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/399) for `inline-flex`, this cannot possibly have worked for you.

Comment: Perhaps it's just putting stuff in span that did work, not `inline-flex`?